# Does IProgress<T> Wait/Block Whilst Updating the UI

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await, progress

All, I have a method that calls `IProgress<T>.Report();` to update my UI and make a relevent data selection. The background thread subsequently picks up the current selection (on the UI) through an interface an works with it. Thus, it is important that the `IProgress<T>.Report();` call blocks the return until the UI update is made. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193864.aspx) provides no information on this aspect of the `Report();` method...

***Does the `Report();` method block the return to the background thread until the `Report();` delegate is finshed?***

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yeah, I get you. But a quick answer will save me 15-20 minutes of testing... Futhermore, a more complete answer will help me understand how the reporting mechanism works fundimentally...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't. It [posts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) - instead of sends - to the synchronization context. A post is asynchronous.

Please note that this is an implementation detail. I learned it from reading the code, I am not aware of any official documentation regarding this.

Furthermore, `SynchronizationContext.Post` is supposed to be asynchronous, but is not guaranteed to be. For example, in ASP.NET the delegate can be invoked directly, i.e. synchronous <sup>[Reference: See Figure 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)</sup>.

Comment: It doesn't have to do that, it depends on the implementation of `IProgress`.

Comment: I meant something else: you can create your own implementation of `IProgress` that does something else, you don't have to use `Progress`.

Comment: @svick: That's correct. Obviously I assumed the OP was asking about the only implementation of that interface that exists in the .NET framework to date. Why that warants a downvote is beyond me.

Comment: I agree, I don't think a down vote is warranted here. This _is_ the answer to my question...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I think that if you assume something that's not actually spelled out in the question, then you should explicitly say that. As it is, I think this answer is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

This depends entirely on the implementation of `IProgress<T>` you're using. If you're going to use the built-in [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx), then `Report()` doesn't wait on the delegate / event handler to complete.

You can create your own implementation of `IProgress<T>` that does what you want (which is most likely calling [`SynchronizationContext.Send()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send.aspx)) and use that.

But I'm not sure this is a good design, I think your worker code shouldn't depend on computations that have to be made on the GUI thread. You might want to considering changing your design.